# Update query needs that all related items to be deleted and re-inserted, which degrades the speed of my application

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the database structure like below:

[image]

When I update order, I use the following query:

```
using (var xaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    foreach (OrderItemDetail orderItemDetail in OrderItemDetailClient.GetAllOrderItemDetails())
    {
        if (orderItemDetail.OrderId == NewOrder.OrderId)
        {
            OrderItemDetailClient.DeleteOrderItemDetail(orderItemDetail);
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<Dispatch> dispatches = DispatchClient.GetAllDispatches().Where(x => x.OrderId == NewOrder.OrderId);
    foreach (Dispatch dispatch in dispatches)
    {
        foreach (DispatchItemDetail dispatchItemDetail in DispatchItemDetailClient.GetAllDispatchItemDetails().Where(x => x.InvoiceId == dispatch.InvoiceId))
        {
            DispatchItemDetailClient.DeleteDispatchItemDetail(dispatchItemDetail);
        }

        DispatchClient.DeleteDispatch(dispatch);
    }

    OrderClient.UpdateOrder(NewOrder);

    xaction.Complete();
    TransactionSucceded = true;
}
```

The UpdateOrder method in OrderClient looks like:

```
public Order UpdateOrder(Order Order)
{
    IOrderRepository OrderRepository = _DataRepositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<IOrderRepository>();

    Order updatedEntity = null;

    if (Order.OrderId == 0)
    {
        updatedEntity = OrderRepository.Add(Order);
    }
    else
    {
        updatedEntity = OrderRepository.Update(Order);
    }

    return updatedEntity;

}
```

And in OrderRepository:

```
protected override Order UpdateEntity(RateDifferenceContext entityContext, Order entity)
{
    return (from e in entityContext.OrderSet
            where e.OrderId == entity.OrderId
            select e).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And then in DataRepositoryBase class I am using the below method:

```
public T Update(T entity)
{
    using (U entityContext = new U())
    {
        T existingEntity = UpdateEntity(entityContext, entity);
        SimpleMapper.PropertyMap(entity, existingEntity);
        entityContext.SaveChanges();
        return existingEntity;
    }
}
```

When deleting the related entities, I get an error: `The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable`

I know that manually I don't need to delete orderItemDetails, Dispatches and DispatchItemDetails before saving the order. But If I don't do that then I get error mentioned below:

```
Multiplicity constraint violated
```

I am really new to entity-framework. Can anybody suggest me a good way to save the order? So that I can get speed.

**Update:**

> Where does NewOrder come from? Is it really new?

`NewOrder` is a property of type `Order`, which is initialized in the Constructor of the ViewModel. As well as when you edit or save. I mean If user is creating a new order than `NewOrder` is new `Order`. And if user is editing an existing order, than `NewOrder` is an `existing Order`.

> What is OrderItemDetailClient. What is DispatchClient?

`OrderItemDetailClient` is a variable of type `IOrderItemDetailService`, which is also initialized in the Constructor of ViewModel as follows:

```
OrderItemDetailClient = serviceFactory.CreateClient<IOrderItemDetailService>();
```

which inturn implies that `IOrderItemDetailService` is the WCF service implemeted class.

Similarly,

`DispatchClient` is a variable of type `IDispatchService`, which is also initialized in the Constructor of ViewModel as follows:

```
DispatchClient = serviceFactory.CreateClient<IDispatchService>();
```

which inturn implies that `IDispatchService` is the WCF service implemeted class.

> What's the role of orderItemDetailList, TotalQuantity, and TotalAmount?

Sorry, that code was not required. I think I forgot to delete that.

> Why do you delete ( and not add) Dispatches?

Update order automatically saves the Order, OrderItemDetail, Dispatch and its related DispatchItemDetail.

So, If I do not delete the existing Dispatches of the NewOrder, then when I update the Order, the Cascade update or something else thinks that I already have a Dispatch with the primary key, that I am now trying to store. So, I get an error :

```
Multiplicity constraint violated. The role '…' of the 
        relationship '…' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1
```

> The most pressing question is: why don't you just add the items that are new, delete the ones that are removed and leave the rest alone?

I think I answered this question in the above answer, that If I do that I get `Multiplicity constraint violated` error when saving the updates.

Comment: There are too many unknows in your code to really follow what happens. Where does `NewOrder` come from? Is it really new? What is `OrderItemDetailClient`. What is `DispatchClient`? What's the role of `orderItemDetailList`, `TotalQuantity`, and `TotalAmount`? Why do you delete ( and not add) `Dispatch`es? In general, all these levels of indirection make your code extremely hard to read, let alone to improve. The most pressing question is: why don't you just add the items that are new, delete the ones that are removed and leave the rest alone?

Comment: @GertArnold I have tried to answer your questions in the Update part of question. So, please refer to it.

Comment: I can only say that you should manage the state of all entities manually. `Attached` or `Modified` for everything that already exists, `Deleted` for everything that should be deleted, and `Added` for everything that's new. If your current code makes that impossible there's only one answer: refactor it and remove concealing layers.

Comment: @GertArnold Can I have an example or tutorial link??

Comment: Have you considered using a stored procedure to delete what you need to be deleted? This will save a number of trips to the database and should be fast. Obviously, you will need to use a new context on the client side since existing ones may be out of sync.

Comment: @Pawel I have not tried that. But surely I will give it a try. But can you please tell me if my code is good right now according to the standards followed by entity framework?

Comment: I have not looked at your code too much. What I see is that you do a ton in a transaction. Normally you want a transaction should be as short as possible. That's a smell for sure. And you bring half of your database to client. Ideally for related entities/rows you would set up relations so that if you remove principal the dependents will be removed as well. It is not always possible so if you really need to do a lot using a stored proc might be better/faster.

Comment: if GetAllOrderItemDetails() brings details of all orders over WCF then that  could be your problem. I would take that call out of the loop into a var and test how long it takes to complete WCF call alone. The same for GetAllDispatchItemDetails().

Comment: What's the point of `Update`? Making new contexts all the time is bad practice. Use one context for your unit of work. This simplifies a lot and might solve your issue. You are working against the EF wants to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very likely that a big part of the problem is that you are potentially pulling a *lot* of data from the WCF service, likely much more than you need. This is expensive because you need to pull the records out of the database and then serialise them in order to pass them out of the WCF service (and then deserialise them on the WCF client).

If you added some methods to the WCF services to return only data that relates to particular IDs then you could limit the data that is returned to only data that is relevant to what you're trying to do, which would speed things up. For example, instead of

```
DispatchClient.GetAllDispatches().Where(x => x.OrderId == NewOrder.OrderId);
```

you could create a service method called "GetDispatchesForOrderId" that takes an order ID and only returns dispatches that relate to it. This would send back only the data that you require and be much cheaper (ie. quicker). So the above line would be replaced with

```
DispatchClient.GetDispatchesForOrderId(NewOrder.OrderId)
```

The trade off is that you have to write a few more service methods.

If you also added methods "OrderItemDetailClient.GetOrderItemDetailsForOrderId" and "DispatchItemDetailClient.GetDispatchItemDetailsForInvoiceId" then your update code would become something like this:

```
foreach (OrderItemDetail orderItemDetail in OrderItemDetailClient.GetOrderItemDetailsForOrderId(NewOrder.OrderId))
{
    OrderItemDetailClient.DeleteOrderItemDetail(orderItemDetail);
}

foreach (Dispatch dispatch in DispatchClient.GetDispatchesForOrderId(NewOrder.OrderId))
{
    foreach (DispatchItemDetail dispatchItemDetail in DispatchItemDetailClient.GetDispatchItemDetailsForInvoiceId(dispatch.InvoiceId))
    {
        DispatchItemDetailClient.DeleteDispatchItemDetail(dispatchItemDetail);
    }

    DispatchClient.DeleteDispatch(dispatch);
}

OrderClient.UpdateOrder(NewOrder);
```

If you don't do something like this then your problem is going to get worse and worse over time as your database grows - every time you will be pulling down more data than you need and as the size of that unnecessary data grows, so will the wasted time that you are spending on pulling down data that you don't actually need.

Comment: As you see in my question and as well as you mentioned in your answer by the last code block that all the records in related entities should be deleted to update an existing order. But when deleting the related dispatches, I get an error: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. Can you please help me on that??

Comment: Are you saying that this line throws the error about foreign keys being non-nullable: "DispatchClient.DeleteDispatch(dispatch);"? Do you have anywhere that a cut down version of this project may be downloaded from, ideally with a sample database the illustrates the problem?

Comment: @Vishal - sorry, I probably should have mentioned in that last comment otherwise you mightn't have seen it.

Comment: I noticed your comment before that. But I was not available at my work, so I didn't checked your code. Yes, I have implemented that. It gives a reasonable difference in performance. But still I feel that my app is slow. Thanks anyway for helping.